# Online Principal Component Analysis with spectral bounds

Tags: algorithm, matrix, r

I have question regarding online PCA implemented in the [paper](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/el327/papers/opca2.pdf). I am interested in the Algorithm 2. I am not certain if there is a bug in my code can someone confirm if my code is correct?  The algorithm is as follows:

> **input**: \$X\$,\$\Delta\$
>   \$U\leftarrow\$ all zero matrix (dimensions are not given in the paper , 0 rows and 0 columns)
>   \$B\leftarrow\$ a covariance sketch
>   **for** \$x_t\in X\$ **do**
>       Add \$x_t\$ to sketch \$B\$
>       **while** \$||(I-U U^{\top})B||^2 \geq \Delta\$
>           Add the top left singular vector of \$(I-UU^{\top})B\$ to \$U\$
>       **yield**\$\;y_t=U^{\top}x_t\$ (I think while loop ends before yielding, not mentioned in the paper)
>   **end for**

Following is the R code I wrote:

```
PCA<-function(X,delta){
    n<-nrow(X)
    d<-ncol(X)
    B<-cov(X)
    Nrow<-nrow(B)
    Ncol<-ncol(B)
    U<-matrix(0,Nrow,Ncol)
    Y<-matrix(0,n,d)
    idx<-0
    for(i in 1:n){
      inc<-X[i,]
        B<-cbind(B,inc)
        Id<-diag(Nrow)
        while(norm((Id-(U%*%t(U)))%*%B,"2")^2 >= delta){
           idx=idx+1
            test<-(Id-(U%*%t(U)))%*%B
            topleft<-as.matrix(eigen(test%*%t(test))$vectors[,1])
            add<-cbind(U,topleft)
            U<-add[,which(!apply(add,2,FUN=function(x){all(x==0)}))]
        }
        y<-matrix(0,1,d)
        if(idx >0){y[1,1:idx]<-t(U)%*%X[i,]}
        Y[i,]<-y
    }
    Y<-Y[,which(!apply(add,2,FUN=function(x){all(x==0)}))]
    return(Y)
}
```

Then to test what I have done make sense I used Fisher iris data, and I got:

```
log.ir <- log(iris[, 1:4])
ir.species <- iris[, 5]


ir.pca <- prcomp(log.ir)
ir.pca$rotation #this is the built in r function equivalent output, which is very different then what I get in my understanding I get (ir.pca$x) from the online PCA implementation.


OPCA<-PCA(as.matrix(log.ir),300)#If you change the value 300 to 0.34 say then you will have X1,X2,X3 and X4
rotationOPCA<-data.frame(t(t(OPCA) %*% as.matrix(log.ir) %*% solve(cov(log.ir))))
```